# Query with DISTINCT clause still returning the same value twice

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using Oracle 11g XE and the following HQL is not working as intended. It for some reason still returns the same value twice.

```
@Query("SELECT y FROM Oferta y, ClassificacaoOfertaBanco c 
        LEFT JOIN c.oferta 
        LEFT JOIN c.banco WHERE y.id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o 
         JOIN o.empresas e WHERE o.id NOT IN 
         (SELECT black.id FROM Banco b 
          JOIN b.blackList black WHERE b.id = ?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL) 
          ORDER BY CASE c.classificacao WHEN NULL THEN y.classificacao ELSE 
          c.classificacao END DESC, y.divulgacaoDe DESC")
```

I am using distinct on the subquery because my Oferta object has some Lob fields, and Oracle doesn't allow distinct on them.

Can someone help me please?

EDIT:
After several tests I am certain the reason for this to be happening is the fact I am selecting from 2 tables. I still don't know how to solve it though.

Comment: `DISTINCT` appears in the subquery after `IN` operator.  It is useless because of `a IN (1, 2)` is same as `a IN (1, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Actually this got me confuse. I have several other queries with DISTINCT inside IN clause and it works as expected. The only difference between this query and the others is this one I am selecting from 2 tables.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT DISTINC y FROM Oferta y, ...`?

Comment: I edited the previous comment, but yes `SELECT DISTINCT y FROM Oferta y`won't work due to the Lob fields inside the object.

Comment: How about `SELECT DISTINCROW y FROM Oferta y, ...`?

Comment: DISTINCTROW is not a valid HQL value

Comment: You seem to be mixing old style joins and SQL 99 joins.  And I'm not seeing any join predicates in an `ON` clause or in the `WHERE` clause.  Unless you're intending to create Cartesian joins...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is something like:

```
@Query("SELECT c.oferta FROM ClassificacaoOfertaBanco c
        LEFT JOIN c.oferta 
        LEFT JOIN c.banco WHERE c.oferta.id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o 
         JOIN o.empresas e WHERE o.id NOT IN 
         (SELECT black.id FROM Banco b 
          JOIN b.blackList black WHERE b.id = ?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL) 
          ORDER BY CASE c.classificacao WHEN NULL THEN c.oferta.classificacao ELSE 
          c.classificacao END DESC, c.oferta.divulgacaoDe DESC")
```

I haven't tested this and I don't have your data model, but the idea is to select from a single base table or entity and follow the relations.

Comment: You were on the right track. Following your idea and using some bidirecional relationship I got the query to work.